# Angular Accept.js breaking unit tests 'Reference Error: Accept is not defined'

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, authorize.net, accept.js

I have an angular component that uses Authorize.nets Accept.js SDK to complete a payment. I don't want to load the Accept.js script unless the user is on the payment screen so I add the script to the page via a method I call on `onInit` in the component.

**some.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit {
  this.addAcceptJsScript();
}

private addAcceptJsScript(): void {
  const element = document.createElement('script');
  element.src = environment.acceptJsUrl;
  element.type = 'text/javascript';
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(element);
}
```

**some.service.ts**

```
declare var Accept: any;

@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
  private sendPaymentToAuthNet(paymentPayload): void {
    Accept.dispatchData(paymentPayload, this.handleAuthNetResponse);
  }
}
```

This works fine for the users as the script is loaded in the DOM and available when the component calls the service that uses the `Accept` API

However my unit test in the service that uses the API doesn't have any reference to what `Accept` is so when it tries to test the line of code where I call `Accept.dispatchData(...)` the test errors out saying *'Reference Error: Accept is not defined"*.

I have tried various ways of mocking Accept but none of them make it available to the test. How do I go about injecting my mock `Accept` into the service so that it's declared when the code tries to use it?

Answer (score 1):

Problems with testing usually indicate flaws in application design.

`document` preferably should be a provider, because it is supposed to be mocked at some point to avoid adding script elements to real DOM. There is [`DOCUMENT`](https://angular.io/api/common/DOCUMENT) provider already that can be injected into the component instead of `document` global. And be mocked in test bed:

```
{
  provide: DOCUMENT,
  useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('document', ['createElement', 'getElementsByTagName'])
}
```

Where `createElement` and `getElementsByTagName` Jasmine spies should be configured to return proper mock objects.

`Accept` should be made a provider for testability reasons as well. The value can be assigned to `window['Accept']` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47944776/3731501) and be mocked in test bed.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to include the path for the Accept.js CDN in my files object in the karma.config

```
files: [
  { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false },
  { pattern: './node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css', included: true, watched: true },
  { pattern: 'https://jstest.authorize.net/v1/Accept.js', nonull: true }
]
```

Comment: I'd expect that you're running unit tests and not integration. Testing against real things is bad in unit tests because this breaks isolation.

Comment: I'm not testing against it, I just need it defined.

Comment: The point here is that real Accept.dispatchData (and more importantly, document.createElement) shouldn't even have a chance to be called in unit test, due to potential side effects. This is what DI is supposed to help with. The alternative is to define window.Accept in beforeEach, which is less idiomatIc to Angular.